# Trouble with checking mysqli_fetch_assoc results

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm having an issue on a personal project. I'm creating a project board where a user can log in, create different projects and add tasks to them. Basically a categorised to do list.
When the user logs in they are redirected to a screen that lists their already created boards. If no boards have been created then a link to "create board" will be displayed

When the user logs in their user name is saved in a session and called with $username

I have two tables, user and boards:

USER:

```
+---------+----------+-----------------+------------+
| user_id | username | email           | password   |
+---------+----------+-----------------+------------+
| 1       |   user1  | user@user1.com  | pass1      |
| 2       |   user2  | user@user2.com  | pass2      |
| 3       |   user3  | user@user3.com  | pass3      |
+---------+----------+-----------------+------------+
```

BOARDS:

```
+----------+-----------------+---------+
| board_id | board_name      | user_id | 
+----------+-----------------+---------+
| 1        |   user1-board1  |  1      |
| 2        |   user1-board2  |  1      |
| 3        |   user2-board1  |  2      |
| 4        |   user2-board2  |  2      |
+----------+-----------------+---------+
```

Note user 3 hasn't created any boards.

I run the below query to pull all associated boards for the current logged in user and display the board name.

```
$query  = "SELECT board_id, board_name, boards.user_id, username ";
$query .= "FROM boards, user ";
$query .= "WHERE boards.user_id = user.user_id ";
$query .= "AND user.username = '{$username}' ";
$set = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
```

This all works fine and when I run the below code I can display the board names.

```
while ($boards = mysqli_fetch_assoc($set)) {
    echo $boards['board_name'];
    echo "<hr/>";
}
```

The problem I am having is displaying a "create board link" when a user is logged in but hasn't created any boards. I.e user 3.

My code:

```
if (!mysqli_fetch_row($set)) {
    echo "create board";
} else {
    while ($boards = mysqli_fetch_assoc($set)) {
            echo $boards['board_name'];
            echo "<hr/>";   
    }
}
```

I have tried variations of the above code but this is the closet i've got. If user 3 (who has no boards) logs in, he is greeted with "create board" so I presume it works as there are no rows of data associated with that user. However, if user 1 logs in (has 2 boards) only the second board name is being displayed. If I remove the !mysqli_fetch_row code then both board names are outputted. Obviously the fetch_row is effecting the results but I can't work out why.

If anyone can offer any guidance in how to check if a user has any boards I would be very grateful. Also if anyone can explain (for my own personal development) why running fetch_row alters my result set that is passed to the while loop it would be a bonus.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
if (!mysqli_fetch_row($set)) {
```

both fetches and consumes a row from the result set.  Since you're not assigning that returned row to a variable, it's utterly lost. If there are rows found, you then go off to the `else` clause, now missing one row of results.

You need to check how many rows were found, THEN start consuming:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($set) == 0) {
   ... there are no rows ...
} else {
   ... there are rows: loop and display them
}
```

Comment: I was actually checking mysqli_num_rows($set) but I was making the mistake of checking it inside the while loop! Obvious now you point it out. Thanks for helping.